# How to store date in some variable in Cypress

Tags: date, variables, store, cypress

Can anyone help me how to store date from a field to variable. Here is the HTML which I am looking at:

```
<input id="date" class="input_date" id="XYZ" type="date" value="2019-01-12" on_input="table()">
```

I tried:

```
const date1 = Cypress.moment(). get('#id_value')
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Hi,
I tried 
const date1 = Cypress.moment().
     get('#id_value')

Comment: [Edit] the question to give a [mcve].

Comment: Can I ask you why the input html has got two ID's ? `Id = date and id =XYZ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Cypress imports the moment library, there are no built in commands for it that allow chaining, but you can add a custom command to make it easier.

The `toMoment()` command must be chained off a previous selecting command like `cy.get()` or `cy.contains()`. It returns a moment object which you can then use invoke to call all the methods moment provides, and further chain `.should()` to test the value returned from those methods.

For example,

**Spec**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('toMoment', {prevSubject: true}, (element) => {
  return Cypress.moment(element[0].value);
});

it('input tests with moment', () => {

  cy.visit('./app/moment-with-input.html');

  cy.get('input').toMoment()
    .invoke('isValid')
    .should('eq', true);

  cy.get('input').toMoment()
    .invoke('format', 'dddd')
    .should('eq', 'Saturday');

  cy.get('input').toMoment()
    .invoke('diff', Date(2020, 2, 5), 'days')
    .should('eq', -391);

})
```

**HTML fragment (put in '/app' folder of project)**

```html
<input id="date" class="input_date" id="XYZ" type="date" value="2019-01-12" on_input="table()">
```

Answer (score 2):

If the ID's are unique, you could try getting the `val` into a variable as below. I have used `date` id in the below code.

*note: In the input `html tag` there `two ID's`, may be need to confirm with dev team which one to be used here*

```
 cy.get('#date').invoke('val').then((val)=>{
   const dateValue = val;
   console.log("Here is the date:"+dateValue);
 })
```

Comment: @user29496 Thats good, ...Please upvote and accept if you are happy:)

Comment: @RichardMatsen When you get some time, can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880864/token-set-gets-removed-while-running-the-cypress-test